# Rails - Include an association in the result of a query

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I would like to get all the addresses of each user in the result.
Doing something like this:

> User.all.includes(:addresses) (User have many address)

And would like to get something like that:

> [[id:1, name:"user1", addresses:[[id:1, street:"5th avenue",
>   city:"ny"], [id:2, street:"grand boulevard", city:"paris"]]], [id:2,
>   name:"user2", addresses:[[id:3, street:"jump street", city:"la"]]],
>   ...]

Because it's a json response.

Comment: So whats your question?

Comment: I would like to get the result formatted like my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
users = User.includes(:addresses).all
users.as_json(include: :addresses)
```

This should return expected result.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It's exactly what I wanted !